# Knockout JS - If bindings inside foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Not sure what I am doing wrong but here is my code.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: publications" >
   <!-- ko if: mediatype === '2' -->
   <li data-bind="text: mediatype, value: id"></li>
   <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

This is returning the whole list in the foreach (all mediatype numbers)

I also tried this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: publications" >
  <li data-bind="if: mediatype === '2', text: mediatype, value: id"></li>
</ul>
```

This returns nothing. Not sure what is wrong here?

Comment: What does your view model look like?

Comment: I think for an expression such as if: mediatype === '2' you'd need to use brackets i.e. if: mediatype() === '2'

Comment: Ah the brackets worked! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Coolness....I should've made that an answer, doh! I added one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an expression such as if: mediatype === '2' you'd need to use brackets i.e. if: mediatype() === '2'